# Frontend custom forgot password page

Tags: password

Is there a shortcode or a function available so that i can show the "forgot password form" on a custom wordpress template? Actually i always have to link to the default lost-password page (/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword) which has the WordPress-Backend styles. I would like to integrate the form in my own template and corportate design

Answer (score 0):

Seems [Frontend Reset Password](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-reset-password/) does what you want. Among other features it also provides you a shortcode to be placed anywhere you want. Styling then is up to you and should be done from your custom (child) theme.

From [Reviews](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-reset-password/#reviews):

> If you are just looking for simlple forget password plugin without
>   other fancy code, this plugin is all you need. I created custom login
>   and registration form for one website and was thinking to build custom
>   forget password and came on this plugin. I just installed it, added
>   shortcode on page and boom. Everything what i need is in there. Just
>   for information, plugin setting page is inside plugin menu. you can
>   also go to plugin list and click on setting link on plugin page.